# Hi I am new in r and trying to use grad in r

Tags: r

```
log1<-function(x,theta){ #make function with 2 argument
    return(-length(x)*log(2*pi)+sum(log(1-cos(x-theta))))
 }
g<-grad(func=log1, theta) # But I am getting an error.
```

1. I am getting an error when I use the gradient function.

Comment: Hi Mary. Your function returns a scalar value when passed vector values of `x` and `theta`, so it's not clear how you expect it to work with `grad`?

Answer (score 1):

your function `log1` requires two arguments `x` and `theta`, but you're only passing `theta`, with no default for either arguments. Try:

```
library(numDeriv)
log1<-function(x,theta){ #make function with 2 argument
  return(-length(x)*log(2*pi)+sum(log(1-cos(x-theta))))
}
g<-grad(func = log1, x=4, theta=5)
```

or assign some default values for your variables so that you can do something like this:

```
log1<-function(x=3,theta=4){ #make function with 2 argument
  return(-length(x)*log(2*pi)+sum(log(1-cos(x-theta))))
}
g<-grad(func = log1, x=c(1,2,3))
```